# jQuery AJAX `always` isn't "always" called

Tags: javascript, jquery

Specifically, when an error is thrown in the `done` (or `fail`) handler, then `always` handler is simply not called.

I've "fixed" this like so:

```
xhr.done(delayThrow(function(response) { /* .. do stuff .. */ }));

function delayThrow(fn) {
    return function() {
        try {
            fn.apply(this,arguments);
        } catch(e) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                throw e;
            },10);
        }
    };
}
```

This works, and (to my surprise) the call stack is left intact*. But it seems like a very hackish solution. Is there a better way, or am I approaching this wrong?

<sub>*I assume this is because the exception object is already created and it's just being thrown without factoring in later call stacks like the `setTimeout`</sub>

Comment: Do you have an example using `always` that reproduces what you mention? Are you using JSONP requests by any chance?

Comment: @Jeto [here you go](https://jsfiddle.net/tmvLw3ch/5/) - in this example two calls are made to `attempt`, one that will trigger an error in the `done` callback, and one that won't. The one that doesn't gets its `always` called, while the one with the error does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, my guess is that the `always` callback is (indeed) a bit misleading and only fires when an error occurred *during* the request, as opposed to *after* it's already done.

Seems like [`deferred.then()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) does the job and gets called in every case. However, this only seems to fire with jQuery 3+, which is why I can't post a SO sample (limited to version 2 apparently).

Demo here:
https://jsfiddle.net/78ux6jhL/

Note that `deferred.then()` takes 3 callback parameters, first one when the initial request was successful, second one when it failed. Just pass the same function twice to emulate the `actuallyAlways` you wanted.